# Polylines not showing correctly in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I'm making a site for a client, and Google Maps is driving me crazy.

I have a map where we include eight polylines from KML-files. Sometimes these lines show up in the map, sometimes they don't. Sometimes only in Firefox. Sometimes only in Chrome. Sometimes only if I zoom in / out. It seems totally random when they show and not.

This is the markup: http://dev.catchmedia.no/r/ringeriksmaraton/tpl/

Does anyone have some suggestions? Would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, not just a link to the problematic web site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to stackoverflow and will provide this next time. I have found the solution: I had **img {max-width: 100%;}** in my StyleSheet. For some reason, Google Maps did not like this.

Comment: Common issue: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+img+%7Bmax-width%3A+100%25%3B%7D

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution: I had **img {max-width: 100%;}** in my StyleSheet. Google Maps did not like this.